# Removing all occurrences of an element from a linked queue

Tags: function, ocaml

I've been tasked with creating a function that deletes all occurrences of a key in a linked queue defined by:

```
type 'a qnode = { v: 'a;
                mutable next: 'a qnode option }

type 'a queue = { mutable head: 'a qnode option;
                    mutable tail: 'a qnode option }
```

I've come up with the code listed below which passes tests I've created for an empty queue and an queue with only one element by times out when the queue has multiple elements with one occurrence of the key in the queue.

```
let delete (elt: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : unit =
if not (valid q) then failwith "delete: given invalid queue";
let rec loop (qn: 'a qnode option) (qn2: 'a qnode option) (elt: 'a) : unit =
  begin match qn, qn2 with
  | None, None -> ()
  | None, Some x   -> if x.v = elt && x.next = None then
                      (q.head <- x.next; q.tail <- x.next)
                      else if x.v = elt && x.next <> None then
                      (q.head <- x.next; q.tail <- x.next; loop x.next q.tail elt)
                      else loop x.next q.tail elt
  | Some x, Some y -> if y.v = elt && y.next = None then 
                      (x.next <- y.next; q.tail <- y.next)
                      else if y.v = elt && y.next <> None then 
                      (x.next <- y.next; q.tail <- y.next; loop y.next q.tail elt)
                      else loop y.next q.tail elt
  | Some x, None -> ()
  end
in loop None q.head elt
```

I'm having trouble finding where exactly I may have an infinite loop, or an inefficient implementation so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic plan for your loop is to let `qn2` range across all the nodes of the queue. At each call `qn` represents the node previous to `qn2` in the queue. You need this previous node in order to update links properly when you find your nodes of interest.

When `qn2` is the first node of the queue, there is no previous node. So `qn` should be `None` in this case.

There are two things to think about for each call: first, what processing to do on the node `qn2`. It might be deleted or it might not be deleted.

Second, how to proceed to the next node of the queue. In other words, what should the recursive call look like? You need to pass a "prev" node (which will be the new `qn`) and a current node (the new `qn2`).

Let's concentrate on this second part of the problem, the specifics of the recursive call. Assume that `qn2` is not `None`, i.e., that there is a node to look at. You should see that if `qn2` is deleted, then the current `qn` will also be the prev node for the next call. If `qn2` is not deleted, `qn2` itself will be the prev node for the next call. In either case the `next` field of the `qn2` node will be the new node to look at (the `qn2` for the next call).

If you look at your two recursive calls, neither of them has the correct form. In particular, the next node to look at is always set to the tail of the queue. This can't be right. You don't want to jump to the end immediately after processing your first node.

Furthermore, if the queue isn't empty, then `q.tail` will always be a node (not `None`). Hence the loop will never terminate.

Comment: This was really helpful. I implemented every suggestion you gave into my function and all my tests passed. It seems that a lot of problems that I face with programming can be solves by stepping back and really thinking about what needs to solved.